# Coding an alphabet in C that shows previous and post letters

Tags: c

So I need this to happen in C, been thinking about it for an hour or so and cant figure out how to do it, or how to ask google something this specific, it has to work with any letter entered.

How to I calculate the next and previous letter in the alphabet for a given letter?

Here is a link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzIZF.jpg

[image]

Comment: You can do arithmetic on char variables. For example 'H' - 1 will give you 'G'

Comment: Just like everything else in computers, letters are represented with numbers, which means you can add and subtract these numbers. The oldest (I think) and most basic standard of number<-->letter mapping is ASCII. A quick google search will tell you the ASCII codes. Also, take a look at this: https://unmad.in/conv_guide/ch01.html

Comment: @samgak It depends on the alphabet in question. A more general solution requires an explicit sequence (say, a string) for the relevant alphabet. And, of course, some letters used in the writing system for a language aren't in the language's alphabet (and that applies to English).

Answer (score 0):

Please review this sample that should do what you want. You must remember to think relative positions, because A-Z is in the middle of ASCII and remember to go around the edges at the letters A and Z so that A is after Z and Z is before A.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int resp;
    printf("Please input an uppercase letter: ");
    resp = getchar();
    int i = resp;
    if ((resp - 1) < 'A')
        i = resp + 26;
    printf("The lowercase version of the letter is: %c\n", tolower(resp));
    printf("The letter %c comes before the letter %c in the alphabet \n", i - 1, resp);
    i = resp;
    if ((resp + 1) > 'Z')
        i = resp - 26;
    printf("The letter %c comes after the letter %c in the alphabet \n", (i + 1), resp);
    printf("%c is letter nr %d in the alphabet \n", resp, resp - 'A' + 1);
}
```

Test

```
Please input an uppercase letter: C
The lowercase version of the letter is: c
The letter B comes before the letter C in the alphabet 
The letter D comes after the letter C in the alphabet 
C is letter nr 3 in the alphabet 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Dac Saunders gave a nice explanation and a good sketch already, I think to have a second, slightly different example might be helpful, too.

```
// for printf() and puts()
#include <stdio.h>
// for exit() and the macro EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <stdlib.h>
// for tolower() and isupper()
#include <ctype.h>

// All calculations assume ASCII encoding!

int main()
{
  char letter;

  puts("Alphabet Facts!");
  puts("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");

  // You want an upper case letter as the input, so check for it
  do {
    printf("\nPlease input an uppercase letter: ");
    letter = getc(stdin);
    // swallow new-line(s)
    getc(stdin);
#ifdef _WIN32
    getc(stdin);
#endif
  } while (!isupper(letter));

  printf("\nSome interesting facts:\n\n");

  printf("  1) The lowercase version of the letter is '%c'.\n\n", tolower(letter));
  if (letter == 'A') {
    // or print 'Z' if you want it to mimic a circle
    printf("  2) No letter comes before '%c' in the alphabet.\n", letter);
  } else {
    printf("  2) The letter '%c' comes before '%c' in the alphabet.\n\n", letter - 1, letter);
  }
  if (letter == 'Z') {
    // or print 'A' if you want it to mimic a circle
    printf("  3) No letter comes after '%c' in the alphabet.\n\n", letter);
  } else {
    printf("  3) The letter '%c' comes after '%c' in the alphabet.\n\n", letter + 1, letter);
  }
  // 'A' is at position 64 in the table of the ASCII encoding but we don't need to
  // look it up, we can use the letter itself because a 'char' is a number, too.
  // The ASCII table is zero based--we need to subtract unity from 'A' or add unity
  // after the subtraction of 'A'.
  printf("  4) %c is letter number %d in the alphabet!\n\n", letter, letter - ('A' - 1));
  // return the special number to the OS that tells it that no error occured.
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```